# Why is the first assignment of str1[0]? Shouldn't it be of str1[1]?

Tags: c, for-loop, pre-increment

In the for loop, we are using `++i` which means that `i` is incremented to `1` before the loop starts to execute. What am I getting wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str1[100], str2[100];
    int i;
    scanf("%s", str1);
    for (i = 0; str1[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        str2[i] = str1[i];
    }
    str2[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*using ++i which means that i is incremented to 1 before the loop starts*" no; what makes you assuming this?

Comment: I don't understand why to downvote this question, it's one of the few questions that makes sense and is very valid.

Comment: For your reference [the related chapter from the C-Standard (draft)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5.3): "*for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement [...] The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after each execution of the loop body.*"

Comment: This is because of the flow of execution of the for loop, ++i is appeared first in the code but reserved for later execution after the body of the loop,when execution control comes to ++i then i is incremented first.however it doesn't matter you preincrement or postincrement in such places where incremention part is not related to any other expression,that is nothing happening between the evaluation of i and incremention of i, as here i++>3 i is compared first with 3 then incremented but in ++i    i    is  incremented first then compared.

Answer (score 5):

The for loop syntax is composed of three statements. The third ("update step") is executed at **the end of the loop body**. So in the first iteration, i is zero.

The expression

```
for(init_stmt; cond_expr; update_stmt)
  body_stmt;
```

Will result in code roughly equivalent to the following:

```
{
  init_stmt;
  while(cond_expr) {
    body_stmt;
    update_stmt;
  }
}
```

Comment: We can call it an update statement rather than an inc_stmt.

Comment: @Rishi - That is indeed a better term for it, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are mistaken: in the context of the increment expression of the `for` statement, `++i`, `i++`, `i += 1` and `i = i + 1` all have the same effect.  Furthermore, this increment expression is executed once **after** each iteration, before evaluating the condition, but not **before** the first iteration.  Here are the steps for the `for` statement evaluation:

1. evaluates the initialization expression `i = 0` ;
2. evaluate the condition expression: if it is false, exit from the loop.
3. evaluate the body of the loop:

   - if a `break` statement is evaluated, exit the loop
   - if a `continue` statement is evaluated branch directly to step 4 ;
   - otherwise, branch to step 4.
4. evaluate the increment expression `++i` ;
5. branch to step 2.

The last statement correctly uses `str2[i] = '\0';`. The value of `i` at the end of the `for` loop is the first that failed the condition, the one for which `str1[i] == '\0'`, which is known as the *length* of the C string in `str1`. This is the index at which you want to store the null terminator in `str2`.

Note that the code can be simplified and made safer this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str1[100], str2[100];

    if (scanf("%99s", str1) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; (str2[i] = str1[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
            continue;
        }
        printf("%s\n", str2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your premise is wrong. `i` is not incremented to 1 before the loop starts.

```
for (initialization_statement; conditional_statement; update_statement) {
    body_of_for_loop
}
```

The way `for` loop works is it executes the initialization statement and then checks if the conditional statement is `true`. If the conditional statement is `true`, the body of the `for` loop is executed. Once the body of the `for` loop is executed, the update statement is executed and then again the conditional statement is evaluated and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For loop syntax:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment or decrement)
{
       //Code
}
```

**Step 1:** Initialize the variable(`i = 0`).

**Step 2::** Check the condition(`str1[i] != '\0'`)

**Step 3:** If condition **True**, then goes to for loop body.

**Step 4:** After successful execution of loop’s body, goes to increment or decrement operation part(`++i`).

See image for more understanding.

[image: img]